# WiX Installer: how to add Firewall exception rule?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, windows-firewall

I install my windows service using WiX installer. It adds Firewall exception:

```
<File Id="file_1000_" Checksum="yes" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceFiles)\MyService.exe">
<fwrules:FirewallException Id="FirewallDomainMySvcTCP"
Name="My Service Domain TCP"
Protocol="tcp"
Port="[PORTNUMBER]"
Scope="any"
IgnoreFailure="yes"
Profile="domain" />
```

My service is a windows host for a few WCF services.

Then I run a query from other workstation to the service, it cannot connect.
I go to Control Panel->Firewall->Advanced->Inbound Rules and see the rule exists but on "Program and services" it has a 
"This program: "
When I mark "All programs that meet the specified conditions" my client connects to the service and works fine.

How I can add in my Installer the Firewall exception rule which is for 
"All programs that meet the specified conditions" but not for one exe?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Solved: 
Remember: you should add ComponentRef to this component into the Fragment(!!!)

The elements

should be under Component but not under File. I moved them on one level upper.
Like this: (check the 1st message: "Component" instead of "File")

...
    
...

...

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: Added the description, if you have a question - please ask.

Comment: Can you make this a full answer including external references such as how you declare your namespace and the position of his in the rest of your configuration?

Comment: By the way: did you click "-"? :-)  why?

Comment: It is large project and installer too. May be it is simpler if you provide you wix project files and describe what you want but cannot do?

Comment: I marked the answer down because it is not a full answer. It does not include external references such as where you declare your namespaces or an explicit description of the position of the component in the rest of the configuration. It is also missing closing tags, so it's incomplete syntax.

Comment: You can use this answer as a reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583509/wix-installer-start-menu-shortcut-not-appearing

Comment: I am trying add rule for bootstrapper. Code is compiling but dont add rule. There is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655355/wix-boostrapper-settings-to-prevent-the-firewall-from-blocking-the-application. Maybe could you help me.