# Wix boostrapper settings to prevent the firewall from blocking the application

Tags: xml, wix, bootstrapper

I can't find anywhere how to set parameters in the wix bootstrapper so that firewalls and anti-viruses do not treat it as a threat. 
My bootstrapper on other devices displays information that it is a threat. Or it doesn't start without any information.

Edit:

I create something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:fw="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension">
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper13" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="" UpgradeCode="86064926-b150-448f-aba9-fb0c8f4a83b5">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />       
    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />
  <MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="..\SetupProject1.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
<Fragment>
...
<PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
  ...
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
<Directory Id="FirewallDirectory" Name="SourceDir">
  <Component Id="cmpFirewallException" Guid="87617436-AE1C-4C87-BB2D-1CA3531DBC46" KeyPath="yes">
    <fw:FirewallException Id="MyFirewallException"
            Program="..\BootstrapperSetup.exe"
            Description="Lets requests through"
            Name="InstallerWix"
            Scope="any"
            Protocol="tcp" />
  </Component>
</Directory>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The code is compiling but it looks like Directory has never started. No new rule is added.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to add a firewall exception for the setup itself. Not possible. And why would you want to do this? Does the setup listen on a TCP port? This would be highly unusual and suspicious?

Comment: I wanted do this for do custom action and change config for IIS. I fund information i should do it in WIX, not bootsrapper. Is that correct?

Comment: What is exactly the prpblem you aer trying to solve?

Comment: When I wrote this I wanted to know how to settings to prevent for firewall. Ale but I read that it should be done as I wrote above

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "prevent for firewall"?

Comment: Create rule in Windows Defender firewall with advanced security because firewall dont let me run application.

Comment: "firewall dont let me run application" - what happens exactly? are you sure it's the firewall - normally the firewall blocks IP communication but does not prevent running an application.

Comment: With the help of what I found on the internet and in the book what I read, I read that you should add rules for the firewall so that the system does not treat this program as a virus. This is what I added in the Directory. But unfortunately I don't see any new rules when I run the program.

Comment: You are on the wrong track. You are confusing the role of a firewall - protection against attacks from the network - with the role of an anti-virus software - protection against malicious programs.

Comment: Ultimately, you don't know why FirewallException doesn't work? Should I call this dictionary somehow, or I have wrong parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a firewall exception to the program installed on client, then you must add a rule for the program that runs on the client. From the code you shown, what I could understand is that you have added the Bootstrapper exe as exception program. (Correct me if its wrong)

Following is a code snippet which I used recently for one of my project to add inbound exception rule for udp packets (ie an exception in Firewall to allow listening for UDP packets from network). This is actually written in the Msi project (in your case SetupProject1)

```
<Component Id="ChangeFirewall" Guid="YOUR-GUID"  KeyPath="yes">
      <fw:FirewallException Id="FirewallExceptionUDP"
                  Name="AppName for UDP"
                  Scope="any"
                  Protocol="udp"
                  IgnoreFailure="yes"
                  Program="[#App_Name.exe]"
                  Profile="all" />  
</Component>
```

For the program, it is the file id of the exe that gets installed on client machine.

```
<Component Id="App_Name.exe" Guid="YOUR-GUID">
    <File Id="App_Name.exe" Name="App_Name.exe" Source="$(var.Project_TargetDir)App_Name.exe">
    </File>
</Component>
```

Comment: Yes I want add this for Bootstrapper exe. As you can see my Component is in Fragment and Directory. I haven't found another way to put it in Bootstrapper. But it doesn't work, I think I should have some call to it in Bundle for him, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by Bootstrapper exe. Is that your program name displayed in Add or Remove after installing the application?

Comment: I mean BootstrapperSetup.exe which is created after the bootstrapper has been compiled.

Comment: You should add the application that is being executed on firewall exception rule, not the setup or bootstrapper application. Say for eg: if you have an exe named "X.exe" and while running that X, you want some specific ports or protocols to allow from network traffic then you should use this firewall exception element for application X.exe.